# Configure both logback.xml and log4j2.xml in a single sprinboot application

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, logback

Hi I have a requirement to configure both logback and log4j2 in my spring-boot application.
It all started with Syslog. Initially, my application had only logback.xml configuration, and I had configured the Syslog appender. But logback does not have support to RFC5424 format. But this is supported in log4j2.

Hence I wanted to configure both which would suffice both of my requirements.

Below is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="/data/storage/log"></property>
<appender name="Console"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/data/storage/log/cms.log</file>
    <encoder
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- roll over daily and when the file reaches 10 MB, max of 7 days or 3GB threshold -->
        <fileNamePattern>/data/storage/log/cms.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.Logs.gz
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<appender name="SPECIFIC_CLASS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/sizeTimeOutputlogFile.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] %p %c{1.} [%t]- %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/sizeTimeOutputlogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!--Max Size of file to start Archive -->
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>

        <!-- Days till log history to keep -->
        <maxHistory>3</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<!--syslog appender-->
<appender name="SYSLOG" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>127.0.0.1</syslogHost>
    <facility>LOCAL0</facility>
    <port>514</port>
    <throwableExcluded>true</throwableExcluded>
    <suffixPattern>%thread: %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</suffixPattern>
</appender>

<!-- LOG everything at ERROR level -->
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>

<!-- LOG "com.myapp*" at ERROR level -->
<logger name="com.myapp" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</logger>
<logger name="sysLogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
</logger>
```

below is log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Configuration strict="true" name="XMLConfig">
<Appenders>
    <Syslog name="Syslog" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="514"
            protocol="UDP" appName="cms" facility="LOCAL0" />
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mavenir.cms.vnf.util.ActivityLogAspect" level ="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Syslog"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But when I run my application syslog does not work.

I could not move from logback to log4j2 because I could not find an equivalent rollingAppender in log4j2.

Comment: Your logging APIs can either be wired as `SLF4J -> Log4j2 API -> Log4j2 Core` or `Log4j2 API -> SLF4J -> Logback`. Both backends can not receive all logs at the same time.

Comment: so you mean to say both configurations are allowed at the same time?

Comment: You can configure both backends, but one of them will **not** receive any log events.

Comment: i just want to get the syslog appender working, would it work if programmatically create a syslog appender using log4j2?

Comment: Why don't you use Log4j2 Core for all logging? Spring Boot makes a lot of effort to forward all major logging APIs (`java.util.logging`, JCL, SLF4J, Log4j2 API) to a single backend. There is not sense in breaking this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and migrate to log4j2

Comment: There is an attribute "totalSizeCap" which helps in accumulating all the rolled-over log files up to a threshold, in my case up to 3GB. Is there an equivalent attribute in log4j2.xml? I see the "max" attribute, but it does not help.